# i didn't understand the recursive implementation of merge_sort sorting algorithm and the function calls

Tags: algorithm, recursion, mergesort

This is a function mergeSort implemented using C programming language, when we're calling recursively the function merge_sort in line 5 and line 6, they're working in parallel or the first one did the job , the rest lines of code are paused ? , what about the line 8 , it's also work in parallel with them?

```
1- void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r)
2- {
    3-if (l < r) {
       4 - int m = l + (r - l) / 2;
       5 - // Sort first and second halves
       6 - mergeSort(arr, l, m);
       7 - mergeSort(arr, m + 1, r);
       8 - merge(arr, l, m, r);
    }
}
```

Comment: You've asked questions before, but never marked an answer as accepted. Any reason for that? There is at least one of those where the answer is of very good quality. If you don't mark answers as accepted, people may be less motivated to look at your questions.

Comment: About this question: implement it in a programming language of your choice and run it using a good debugger, step by step, and it will answer your question.

Comment: Whether these lines are run in parallel or sequentially depends on the language you are using. Can you add that to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All programs execute line by line. There will not be any parallel mechanism unless you do multithreading which your code clearly didn't.
line 5 will be executed after line 4
line 6 will be executed after line 5
line 7 will be executed after line 6
line 8 will be executed after line 7

If you don't believe the code is actually executed one line by one line. Here I will provide an example.

```c
// a recursive function, like mergeSort
void print(int i, int j) {
    printf("%d %d\n", i, j);
    if (j > 0) print(i, j - 1);
}

int main() {
    print(1, 2);
    print(2, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 2
1 1
1 0
2 2
2 1
2 0
```

It is now clear that print(1, 2) get **fully** executed before print(2, 2)

Comment: Can you share more details? What makes you think that this is not run in parallel?

Comment: @NicoHaase This will not run in parallel. There is no mutli-threading code here.

Comment: How do you know that? Which program language do you assume?

Comment: @NicoHaase In order for it to be run parallel. The compiler or interpreter needs to know those code won't affect each other and put them on different threads. However, when you look at the code it is simply impossible for compiler/interpreter to know. Inside a single thread, it is clear that instruction will only get executed one by one and no parallel execution.

Comment: @NicoHaase Any language actually, it looks like Java. However, the same will apply for any other languages like JavaScript, Python, C, etc.

Comment: The compiler or interpreter for which language? What makes you think that there is not a single language that could interprete the given lines in parallel?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235889/discussion-between-anson-yeung-and-nico-haase).

Comment: My question is when we pass parameters to the function in line 6 we wait until it ends ? And begin line 7 too ? Or what ?

Comment: This is C programming language program

Comment: @bwass31 Yes, we wait until the function ends. similar to how you wait for line 4 to calculate m before executing line 5

Comment: So , if the code is executed line by line, the parameters passed to the function use their own stack frame and doesn't change the parameters for the next line function call right? , I want to understand that from memory prospective please

Comment: @bwass31 Yes, you're right. Each recursive function call will have its own stack frame. Therefore, if there is too much recursive call (for example, a recursive function that call itself forming an "infinite loop" of calling itself `void a() { a(); }`), the call stack will be filled with data from the stack frames and stack overflow error will occur. This is why the error is called stack overflow.

Comment: In the context of C this will be segmentation fault. Either way it will cause memory issue to occur instead of like an actual infinite loop which can keep running without error.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir I really appreciate your help! Thanks to nico too !